# BigDecimal Exponentiation

Tags: java, algorithm, bigdecimal, exponentiation

I am making a custom BigDecimal class (for practice and out of boredom) and have custom-made algorithms for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, and I would like to make a function for exponentiation, but since a power with a decimal part involves n-roots, I can think of no simple way to exponentiate. My class works by having two BigIntegers (not the java.math.BigInteger class, but my own class that contains `String BigInteger.number` for which contains the number and `boolean BigInteger.negative` which, obviously, tells whether or not the number is negative.), one of which is the integer part (`BigInteger BigDecimal.ipart`) of the number and the other is the fraction part (`BigInteger BigDecimal.fpart`.) It also contains `boolean BigDecimal.negative` and `long BigDecimal.precission`, which defines how precise to be in division. My question is, does an algorithm exist that will work well with my current setup?

*Note: The two .java files can be found here.. [BigInteger.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2UlFH2ieIEiREVzcHF1c2x1Q00/edit?usp=sharing) & [BigDecimal.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2UlFH2ieIEiQVo0YW5QdlBNX00/edit?usp=sharing)*

Comment: Yes, please do privide your implementation. Most of us think better looking at the code.

Comment: @InduDevanath I have added links to the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, pow(a,b) is computed as exp(b * ln(a)). Both exp() and ln() are calculated up to a certain precision from their series (e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples)). All you need are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division operations which you already have.

Since your numbers are always real rationals, as you mentioned all you need are integer exponentiation algorithm, n-th root algorithm, and careful checks to confirm that it exist (e.g. sqrt(-1) should be NaN). There are various algorithms that use only +-*/ to compute n-th roots, such as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm).

**update:** [here's another n-th root algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth-root_algorithm) with only integer arithmetics.

also, if you have efficient implementation of integer exponentiation, you can binary search for the answer.

These are the simplest methods I can think of right now that fit your current setup.